# Flow types - Casting HTMLElement to HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have the following code:

```
const metricsInputEl = document.querySelector(
  'input[name="metrics"]',
);

const value = metricsInputEl.value;
```

But I'm getting the following Flow error:

```
Cannot get metricsInputEl.value because:
 • property value is missing in HTMLElement [1].
```

How do I get around this issue?

The following works but I'm not that keen on it because that `instanceof` check will not be stripped away and I don't want it to be part of my bundle and doing redundant typechecking during runtime.

```
const metricsInputEl = document.querySelector(
  'input[name="metrics"]',
);

if (metricsInputEl instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
  const value = metricsInputEl.value;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be able to take advantage of Flow's [Comment Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/comments/). You can perform the `instanceof` check inside a Flow comment, which will satisfy Flow's type system but should be removed by the transpiler.

```
const metricsInputEl = document.querySelector(
  'input[name="metrics"]',
);


/*::
if (!(metricsInputEl instanceof HTMLInputElement)) {
  throw new Error('element is not of type HTMLInputElement');
}
*/

const value = metricsInputEl.value;
```

Note that this can be dangerous since an element with `name="metrics"` is not guaranteed to be an `HTMLInputElement`, but if you're confident that this will always be true, it can be a good way to satisfy Flow.

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you for teaching me about Comment Types! Never knew it existed!